# Forcing Skype window resize (under Gnome)

Tags: gnome, x11, window, skype

Using Skype 2.2 on Linux, the video which is reproduced seems to be limited to 320x240; the default options to resize the window are disabled.

Is there a way to force a resize of this window? Just integer scale would be acceptable (eg. 2x only)...

Comment: In Skype, hit `f` and it goes full-screen. I don't know of a middle-ground though.

Comment: Very interesting - didn't know that; thanks @ams, I will give that a try and report back! (although now that I think of it, full screen is not really what I need, just a slightly enlarged window) Cheers!

Comment: Bump - just to confirm, `f` does indeed go full-screen, but I'd like to have just a scaled window instead... Thanks, @ams - cheers!

Answer (score 3):

Try to resize the Window with alt+middle mousebutton. Or try [`wmctrl`](http://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) to force a resize:

```
wmctrl -r "Windowname" -e g,x,y,w,h
```

Change Windowname into the one you want to be resized.

- g -> gravity, just set it to 0 you're good to go
- x -> x position on your desktop, 0 is left
- y -> y position on your desktop, 0 is top
- w -> new width for the window in pixel
- h -> new height for the window in pixel

Example:

```
 wmctrl -r "Firefox" -e 0,0,400,800,600
```

Changes a Window containing "Firefox" in it's Windowtitle to 800 x 600 and moves it to 0x400 on the desktop.

Comment: i tried this with the gedit About window, which isn't resizeable too, and it didn't worked maybe it's not possible to do this without a resource hacker.

Comment: Thanks for this tip, @PierreGeier - will give this a try and report back - cheers!

Comment: Ok, as first - the alt+middle button doesn't work on the Skype video window; if you actually right-click that window's top bar, it is visible that the "Resize (Alt+F8)" option is disabled/greyed out - probably that's why.. So that trick will not work here (but thanks for the tip anyways)...

Comment: Ok, checked with `wmctrl` - that doesn't work either; first problem is that the name of the video call window isn't constant, as it contains the duration of the call (e.g. "04:12 | call with userX") - so I used `wmctrl -l` to obtain ID's; and then `wmctrl -r -i 0x000... -e` - but nothing seems to happen.. Thanks anyways, @PierreGeier - cheers!

Comment: You're welcome, btw wmctrl doesn't need the full Windowtitle wctrl -r "call with somedude" ... would work too if the window would be resizable.

Comment: I would like to make +1s several times

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem with the new skype for Linux 3.18, I found that the resize option was greyed out when you try to use it. Through some basic fiddling with the options on the interface, you can reset the window by going to "View" and clicking "actual size", check to see if the resize option is now available, if not, close the program down, and relaunch. The resize option should now be available again. It seems that there is a minimal desktop area which skype will allow, so when you resize notice how items in the interface change, so adjust according to your tastes, but do not try to exceed the minimum area set, otherwise you're back to square one.